# IFS formula in the table

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I need some help with an table I'm building. It has an IFS statement on it but I am not sure why its not working properly.

Here is the link for the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TgeCfni7fqvSUt1dTq4nwOX37p50OrfszWDZgW62hw0/edit?usp=sharing

Ask:    In E2, should show 2 since B2 greater than 12 % but keeps on showing 1 instead

Get a correct IFS formula for the table

Comment: You need to give a clear example in the question, some of us will not download a file from an unknown source. As for an error with if() have you checked what  you are testing compared to what you think you are testing?

Comment: B2 value: 12%  C4: 7%        C5: 12%                                                                                          if B2 is Greater than or equal to 12% it should return 2; Between 12% and 7% should return 1; Less than 7% should return 0. the formula I have:  
              =IFS(B2>$C$5,2,B2<$C$4,1, B2>$C$4,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B2` expanded with decimals showcases that its`<C5`

[image]

Comment: As I said above, need to know what one is testing.